# How to read .docx file using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, docx, desktop

I want to create Windows desktop app which can extracts data from .docx files and manipulates it in every possible way.
But when I try to read data from file I get an exception - `FileSystemException: Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8'`

Here my code:

```dart
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.any);
    if (result != null) {
      try {
        File file = File(result.files.first.path!);
        fileString = await file.readAsString();
      } catch(e) {
        log(e.toString());
      }
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: A docx file is a zip archive so it's a raw byte stream. It can't be converted to a string as utf-8 (`file.readAsString()`).  If you want to get the content of the docx file you need to first extract the XML files from the zip archive. https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/docx/

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. Do you know how to extract the XML files?

Comment: Both https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/archive_io/archive_io-library.html and https://pub.dev/packages/archive can unpack zip files. I haven't used archive_io but I have used the archive package (second link) to extract zip files to temp storage and haven't had any issues with it.